# Old AMD on Windows 7 64-bit; is Cool'n'Quiet possible?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cooling, noise

Can I enable Cool'n'Quiet on my old AMD processor on Windows 7 64-bit? If so, do I need a separate driver (like Windows XP) or I only have to modify some options?

The processor is an AMD Athlon 64 3200+ on an ASUS K8V-MX motherboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling Cool’n’Quiet on Windows 7 is the same as it is on Windows Vista…

**DOs:**

- C’n’Q must be “enabled” in the motherboard’s BIOS (Note that most BIOS settings disable it by default)
- For optimal power savings, be sure to also enable C1E and DRAM Power Down in the BIOS
- The power management scheme/setting must be "balanced" or "power-saver" in the control panel (note that this is the default setting)
- The motherboard’s BIOS must recognize the CPU that is installed (BIOS status screen will properly display CPU model number upon boot-up)
- You can verify C’n’Q is working with a utility tool such as “CPU-Z” or “AMD Power Monitor.”

**DON'Ts:**

- Do NOT Select “Performance” as Windows 7’s power management scheme/setting as it will disable C’n’Q functionality
- Do NOT manually set the CPU frequency or multiplier in the BIOS. Doing so will lock the processor speed and disable C’n’Q functionality
- Having an old BIOS that does not properly recognize the CPU may disable C’n’Q functionality (flash your BIOS to latest version)
- There is NO need to install a separate AMD CPU driver… **Windows 7 has the AMD CPU driver built-in already!**

*[Source](http://forums.legitreviews.com/about22979.html)*

Comment: Thanks, never runned Windows Vista (Jumped from XP to Se7en) and I was using high performance power scheme.

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the question did not ask about "optimal" power savings, so do NOT follow all the "DOs", nor are all the "DON'Ts" correct.

- You do not need to enable DRAM power down, it's just not applicable.
- BIOS doesn't need to recognize the CPU, that's why there are settings for it instead of auto-set (no setting).
- You CAN set the CPU frequency or multiplier in the BIOS. I'm typing on a system where I have done this and C'n'Q is verified working in CPU-Z, on Win7 x64.  However if you are overclocking you have an additional stability concern which is whether the CPU is stable at the lower C'n'Q voltage and this is not something you can check with a stress test because that kind of test puts the CPU at full speed and power.  Rather you would watch out for windows errors that don't otherwise occur with C'n'Q disabled.

Short version:  There is nothing you are likely to need to do.  Do check that cool 'n quiet is enabled in your bios but if it was a fresh windows install with that CPU, it is already set up to work by default.  If it was not a fresh install you ought to do one, but you probably already know that if you're adept enough to get windows to re-plug-n-play everything the 2nd time.